# Flutter: How to properly listen to providers changes when on details page?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my question, I have a simple grid list, where each tile contains a text and a favorite icon.

That grid is linked to a provider (which contains all the data), and each tile is linked to a nested provider which points to an individual element of the list provided above.

Now when I click on a tile I navigate to a details page, which just shows the name of the object, a favorite icon (outlined or not if the object is favorite or not) and a button "mark as favorite".

(I do that via Navigator with an argument representing my object, that I retrieve after from the grid provider)

Now when I click on the button I want to mark that object as a favorite, which is working fine (in the grid it shows the good status thanks to the provider), BUT how do I update my details page right away ?

Should I always use a stateful widget in that case ? or is there another way to "listen" to my item provider ?

I suppose that somehow I should be able to mark my details page as a listener of my provider, but I don't know how cause the details page is not in the same hierarchy as my grid tile...

Thanks for any feedback on this !

Comment: Can you share some code? Is your dependency injection local or global? For that favoruite feature you can use StatefulWidget also, Provider is not a must for this.